# Add row to gridview from a button c# VB.FORM

Tags: c#, sql

Good morning, I am trying to add from 1 button 1 new row to my gridview form in c # vb.net and sql server, but I can't find the function to add 1 new row to the gridview using a button

[image]

So far I have only shown the records to the gridview this is my code to display data.

```
 private void txtcod_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtcod.Text == "")
        {



        }
        else {

            this.dgvcontactos.DataSource = negCli.DatosContacto(MODULOS.Globales.Base, txtcod.Text);
        
        }
    }
```

---

this is my data_layer where I have 1 function that calls a stored procedure

```js
  public DataTable Contactos_ClieProvs(String basesita, String codClie)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(conexion.CargarBase(basesita));
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("execute CONTACTOS @tipo=13,@IdClieProv='" + codClie + "'", cnn);
                //cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                try
                {
                    if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        cnn.Open();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cnn.Close();
                        cnn.Open();
                    }
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
                catch (SqlException ex) { throw ex; }
                finally
                {
                    cnn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex1) { throw ex1; }
            return dt;
        }
```

Through a stored procedure in my database, a select * from contacts, I am working with N layers, all good up to that point, what I want is by means of a button to add 1 row to the gridview once the row that is saved with the save button is filled, they will have any ideas.

Comment: It is unclear how the grid is filled with data. Does it have a data source? If it does, then you could add the row to the data source. Or possibly set the grids `AllowUserToAddRows` to true, which will leave an extra “empty” row at the bottom of the grid in which the user can add rows without clicking the button. In addition, is there some reason you did not post the code in the button’s click event? Just a thought.

Comment: I understand your point of view in case it were so, leave the gridview with AllowUserToAddRows as it would do once the grid is completed, save it to the database, any ideas?

Comment: The grid has events you can subscribe to fire when the user adds a row. You could possibly “save” the new data after the user leaves the new row. If there is data validation needed in the new row, then possibly open a popup form to add the new data then your code could add the row after the data is validated. You can certainly do the validation in the grid itself as the user enters text into the cells, however, if there is a lot of validation, I am confident a popup form to add the data will make the validation much easier.

Comment: Use a local DataTable variable: `DataTable dt = negCli.DatosContacto(MODULOS.Globales.Base, txtcod.Text);`  Set the grid to that variable.  Now you can add a row to `dt` and it will automatically appear in the grid.  Side note: A SqlDataAdapter can open and close the connection as needed, so you can get rid of all that code in the `Try {}` block above the `da.Fill(dt);` line and the `Finally {}` block.  Do favor `using {}` blocks for disposable objects in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a row to your DataTable and it will show up on the grid.

But it is always good to consider using a BindingSource where you can set up the initialization of a new row by event.

```
System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bs = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource();
private void txtcod_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ("" == "") return;

    var dt = negCli.DatosContacto(MODULOS.Globales.Base, txtcod.Text);
    bs.DataSource = dt;
    bs.AddingNew +=bs_AddingNew;
    dt.RowDeleting +=dt_RowDeleting;
    this.dgvcontactos.DataSource = bs;
}

void dt_RowDeleting(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    // Delete from db
}

void bs_AddingNew(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AddingNewEventArgs e)
{
    // init new row columns with init values in e.NewObject;
}

private void btnAddNew(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    bs.AddNew();
}

private void btnSave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var dt = bs.DataSource as DataTable;
    foreach(DataRow r in dt.GetChanges().Rows) {
        if(r.RowState == DataRowState.Added) {
            // Save to db
        }
        if(r.RowState == DataRowState.Modified) {
            // Save changes
        }
    }
    dt.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Comment: works great when adding a new row and until the save button, a query this if (r.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
                {
                    // Save Changes
                }

is to modify the selected row true